# Firebug is stopping even where no breakpoint is set

Tags: firebug

I'm using Firebug to debug javascript. 
It keeps breaking at heaps of places even though there are no breakpoints set. So, I find myself playing through about 30 places in the jQuery library where the debugger is stopping.

I've probably accidentally set some setting to a value to make it do this. It is not the yellow pause button.

Does anyone recognise this symptom. How can I go back to productively debugging javascript, so that it only stops at breakpoint set by me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. I just reset all options in Firebug.

To do this:

1. click on the bug
2. click the Options menu item (which slides a new
   menu to the right)
3. click the item "Reset All Firebug Options"

That cleared it up.

Cheers

Comment: Brilliant. Instead of spending 10 minutes trying to find it, I should have just google'd right away.

Comment: I also, needed to **restart firefox** after that operation, thanks for saving me some time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem firebug stopped in every exception.
I am not sure from what version this exists but I have Firefox v59.
In debugger tab disable "Ignore exceptions. Click to pause on uncaught exceptions". The right icon above "Watch expressions"

[image: The right icon above "Watch expressions"]

Comment: Is Firebug even still a thing in 2018?

Comment: It is not enough for me. Firefox blocks for some events. With big JavaScript applications, it is impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem still exists in Firefox 88.0 (64bit): a source line breakpoint is sometimes hit after it has been cleared. I found that the breakpoint can be cleared by simply restarting Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists in the debugger in Firefox 75.0. The only way I found around it, apart from reinstalling Firefox, was to delete the pref.js file. In my Windows 7 it is found under C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile]\